# Java EE outputText with method & parameter, inside dataTable

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am new to Java Enterprise, sorry if this has been answered,I could not find anything specific. I am trying to loop through a datatable, and call a method with the id from every result and display some info. 
My XML looks like this:

```
        <h:dataTable styleClass="data" value="#{moduleBean.allModules}" var="m" class="modulelist">
      <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{uistrings.module_name}</f:facet>
      #{m.name}
      </h:column>
      <h:column>
          <f:facet name="header">#{uistrings.approved}</f:facet>
              <h:outputText value="#{moduleBean.findStats(m.id}"/>
      </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

moduleBean.allmodules() returns a list of module objects. This works fine.
The problem is moduleBean.findStats().

Error message:

```
    javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no.uia.slit.web.ModuleBean$$OwbNormalScopeProxy0.findStats(java.lang.Long)

viewId=/teacher/status.xhtml
location=D:\code\github\neiva\build\web\teacher\status.xhtml
phaseId=RENDER_RESPONSE(6)

Caused by:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException - no.uia.slit.web.ModuleBean$$OwbNormalScopeProxy0.findStats(java.lang.Long)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1773)

/teacher/status.xhtml at line 27 and column 72 value="#{moduleBean.findStats(m.id)}"
```

If I change the method to not take any parameters, and call it like "#{moduleBean.findStats"} it works, but how can I pass parameters to the method?

the method is defined like this:`public String findStats(long id){}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try defining the method to receive a Long (object) instead of long (primitive).

```
public String findStats(Long id){}
```

Comment: Wow. that actually worked, thanks alot. I Didn't even know "Long" with capital L was a thing.

Comment: In Java for each primitive type there is a wrapper class. This way you can use any primitive type value as an object, for instance Integer i = new Integer(100); It may be useful to read a little about these wrapper classes.